# How to create a right-click keyboard shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is there any shortcut to have the same effect as the right click of the mouse as I don't have the menu button on my laptop

If not, is there any alternative way such that I can make it possible

I am using Ubuntu-gnome14.04

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to install `xdotool`, with which you can a.o. simulate key (combinations) and mouseclicks.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

then open `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts`, set a key combination you like, and make it run the command:

```
xdotool click 3
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it opens the right click menu where the mouse pointer is and not where the keyboard cursor is. This is a bit problematic, if one is writing a text and wants to have a right click menu, e.g. to get spelling suggestions for a misspelled word. I think the keyboard key for right click does that for the text cursor.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Ubuntus you can do that with Shift+F10